# How to call a constructor from a class, in main method

Tags: java, methods, constructor, program-entry-point

I know this is probably a super simple question but I can't seem to figure it out for the life of me.

As the title states I just want to call the constructor in the Main Method.

```
class Example{
  public static void main (String[] args)
  {
   //I want to call the constructor in the mpgCalculator class....
  }

  public class mpgCalculator {
    public double compute(double mpg, double sizeOfTank)
    {
      double mpL = mpg * 4;
      double tankSizeL = sizeOfTank * 4;
      double kmpL = mpL * 1.6;
      double result = kmpL / tankSizeL;

      return result;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: In Java, class names should start with a capital letter (`MpgCalculator`). This isn't a language requirement, but it's a universal convention, and it makes reading your code much easier.

Answer (score 3):

The class `mpgCalculator` only has the default constructor since you didn't define one. You don't call the constructor manually; instead, you create a new object and it's called automatically. You probably want this:

```
mpgCalculator calc = new mpgCalculator();
```

In this particular case, the `compute` function doesn't actually relate to any particular copy of `mpgCalculator`, and so you can make it `static` if you want (`public static double compute`). Then in another method you can say:

```
double kmpL = mpgCalculator.compute(mpg, size);
```

Answer (score 3):

To add additionally to the problem; you appear to be using an inner class. You cannot instantiate the class the way you have built it without having an object of Example first.

EDIT: two examples of possible resolutions to your problem:

First, static inner class; essentially like a nested class of C++. The inner class does not need to be associated with another instance.

```
public class InnerClassTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        InnerClass test = new InnerClass();
    }
    public static class InnerClass {
        InnerClass() {
          System.out.println("test");
        }
    }
}
```

Second, the complicated inner class instantiated from the outer class.

```
public class InnerClassTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        InnerClassTest example = new InnerClassTest();
        InnerClass test = example.new InnerClass();
    }
    public class InnerClass {

        InnerClass() {
            System.out.println("test");
        }

    }
}
```

If you just need a utility function, then follow chrylis's answer.

Comment: Like this?

`class Example{
  public static void main (String[] args)
  {
  
  
  }
 
  public class mpgCalculator {
    
  mpgCalculator calc = new mpgCalculator();
  public double result = calc.compute(1.0,2.0);
  
  
    public double compute(double mpg, double sizeOfTank)
    {
      double mpL = mpg * 4;
      double tankSizeL = sizeOfTank * 4;
      double kmpL = mpL * 1.6;
      double result = kmpL / tankSizeL;
      
      return result;
    }
    
  }
  
}`

God I suck at this.

Answer (score 0):

Since, `mpgCalculator` (which should be renamed to `MpgCalculator` or `MPGCalculator` to differentiate it from variable names) is an inner class of `Example` you need an outer class instance to instantiate it.

```
double value = new Example().new MpgCalculator().compute();
```

But, this seems like a utility class in which case you can have it nested by making it `static`.

```
public static class MpgCalculator {
    // ...
}
```

You could then create its instance without needing to create an outer class instance too.

```
double value = new MpgCalculator().compute();
```